# Running npm install -g yo command gives -> ERR

Tags: javascript, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I just tried to do a npm install but get this error.

```
npm install -g yo
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/hemanth
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hemanth/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I changed the permissions of /usr/local with chown, but I'm not sure if this affects my issue.
How can i fix it?

Comment: try running the console under Administrator priviledge!

Comment: Whatever you do, don't do what @Sunny says

Comment: Have you changed the permissions with "sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local" ?

Comment: @MarioAlejandroAraque ..i used this command sudo chown -R user2/usr/local

Comment: You should never change permissions of system files and folders.

Comment: How did you install Node?

Answer (score 3):

### Edit

Ah, I read your OS wrong, you're on a mac. I'll leave this here though as it might still work (assuming you installed node via Homebrew)

---

I've only recently been playing with `npm` on Linux and this is how I solved it...

First, set the global npm prefix to a local (to your user) install

```
mkdir ~/.node && npm config set prefix ~/.node
```

npm up to and including version 1.4.20 is buggy (it ignores `prefix` configuration) so first thing we're going to do is install the current `npm` local to your user.

```
npm install -g --prefix=~/.node npm
```

Now all that's left to do is update your environment variables. In `~/.bashrc` or whatever your preference is...

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.node/bin" ]; then
    PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
fi

export NODE_PATH="$NODE_PATH:$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules"
```

Then source it and you're good to go

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/185441/what-does-the-sudo-command-do) as to the reason the following command should work for you

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

Answer (score -1):

try with

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm install -g yo
```

Comment: You should explain your answer. What does it do and why should it work?